# Play and encode audio in reverse?

Tags: 14.04, encoding, playback, audio-player

Using tools available to Trusty Tahr how can I play audio files in reverse (play them backwards)? I would also like to know of tools that will allow me to save or create such reversed audio files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### From GUI with [Audacity -](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=audacity) [image: Install audacity]

[Reversing audio](https://web.archive.org/web/20160413011833/http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/reverse.html) can be done using Audacity *Effect > Reverse*. After reversing we can choose to just playback or to export in any codec supported.

#### From CLI with [Sox -](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sox) [image: Install sox]

On the command line we can reverse audio with [**sox**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/sox) option `reverse`:

```
sox input.wav output.wav reverse ## for conversion
play input.wav output.wav reverse ## for playback
```

Comment: Thank you for this which deals with encoding. For 'reverse playback' of unmodified I have only seen so far playback from within Audacity itself (after the Reverse effect is used) and the `play` utility of sox which will work as: `play input.wav reverse`. Feel free to add these and any others you know of to your answer... There must be more!